# vi with files/directories on the side?

Tags: text-processing, vim, vi, programming

I'm wondering if there's a plugin or a way to make vi/vim have collapseable folders/files on the left side like a regular IDE.

Comment: Look into the NERDTree plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello I think this one is good enough for most cases

https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree